# Checking for login credentials in HTML5 Storage

Tags: javascript, json, function, authentication

i'm building a quizz app , which asks me to : Add user authentication: allow users to log in, and save their login credentials to local storage (HTML5 browser storage). what i want to add is to check if the user name && password (together, because you can have the same username and not the same password and vice versa), so i can prompt a "Welcome back (name of the user)".
i spent 3 days trying to figure out which logic works , tried everything but every time i get a logic problem where things doesn't go the way it should be , here's the code :

```
  var usersinfo = {
       users : []
  }

 localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(usersinfo.users))

 function registerInfo(){
  var name = document.forms[0].username.value;
  var pw = document.forms[0].pw.value;

  if (name === "" || pw === "") {
   alert ('please complete all the forms')
    } else {
    var adding = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    // logic that goes here : i tried everything , looping...etc 
   }

return false;
}
```

Note that the function is attached to a button , and everything works fine on the HTML , the problem is in login logic .

Comment: Logic for what?  What are you trying to do?  What specifically is this "logic problem"?

Comment: what i'm trying to do , checking if the username and the password entered by the user does both exist in the localstorage object , if not add them , else prompt ('welcome back')

Comment: You should be getting the `localStorage` value first thing and then checking it to see if it actually exists. If it does, the user is authenticated. If not, then they need to authenticate and that's when you would grab their data and place it into `localStorage`.

Comment: Look into using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try something like this:

```
const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
if (users.some((user) => {
  return user.name === document.forms[0].username.value;
})) {
  alert('Welcome back!');
}
```

Basically, we use `some` on the array to loop through and figure out if any of the elements have the same name as the one from your form.  If they do, we immediately stop looping and return `true`.  If not, we return `false`.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

And, do take @AnilRedshift's advice and don't store usernames/passwords in localstorage...